# Why i am not able to install "node-sass-middleware"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-sass

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lC9zJ.png)

why it us showing this errors when i type,

```
npm install node-sass-middleware
```

why it's failing to install it?i want to install that package for nodejs project,i tried to reinstall npm etc etc

Comment: https://github.com/sass/node-sass-middleware/issues/137 You probably shouldn't use that package.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! code 1